# Magento2: URL re-write issue with prameters?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, url-rewrite

trying to re-write the url but it not hitting the target link having '?' in that .

for example:

request path: **http://localhost/test/data/products**

traget path : **http://localhost/new/vendors?id=5&type=new**

i want to achieve the above format but its giving "404: The page you requested was not found".

**Note: I am able to hit the urls without "?" in it.**

Comment: are you able to access this url directly ? - http://localhost/new/vendors?id=5&type=new

Comment: @ManthanDave yes..its working perfectly

Comment: ok then have run indexer:reindex command ? after url re-writing

Comment: done everything...clearing/flushing the cache.. I believe some issue with using the "?" in target link ??

Comment: Well if you can access -  http://localhost/new/vendors?id=5&type=new - this url with question mark directly then i guess not issue with request path

Comment: trying the same thing since yesterday.. but no luck